# Notepad++: how to find Numerical or a alpha-numerical between special chareters

Tags: notepad++, numerical

For example: In the text i need to find numerical in between chareters ''
like '87646790345' or '353632249' or '7668GHN876FB766HN'

Comment: have a look at regular expression here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

notepad++ allows you the ability to use regex to find and replace content in the file

Answer (score 3):

To find numbers only between single primes search for `'\d+'` or for `'[0-9]+'`. To find letters and numbers between single primes search for `'[a-z0-9]+'` making sure that **Match case** is not selected. To search for find letters, numbers and underscores between single primes search for `'\w+'` or `'[a-z0-9_]+'` making sure that **Match case** is not selected. In all cases make sure that **Regular expressions** are selected.

The `\d` means digits. The `[` and `]` enclose a range of characters, so `[a-z0-9_]` means `a` to `z` inclusive plus `0` to `9` inclusive plus `_`. To include a `-` in the range of characters it needs to be the first or last character. So `[-a-d]` would search for a `-` plus `a` to `d` inclusive. The `+` in the above search expressions means look for one or more of the preceding items. So `\d+` means search for one or more adjacent digits. Finally, the `'` characters in the searches represent themselves. So `'\d+'` means search for a single prime followed by one or more digits followed by another single prime.

You can search for only upper case or only lower case letters by selecting that **Match case**. Then, for example, `[ABCdef]` would not find `a` or `b` or `E` etc.